# Find center coordinates of regions in a 3d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, scipy

I have a large numpy 3d array (10000, 3, 3). in which I would like to find the center coordinates of each region (clusters with the same number). Each sub-array can have 1, 2, 3 or 4 regions.

A subset of my array is:

```
largearray= array([[[1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 2],
    [3, 0, 2]],

   [[0, 0, 4],
    [0, 0, 4],
    [0, 0, 4]],

   [[5, 0, 0],
    [5, 0, 6],
    [0, 6, 6]],

   [[7, 0, 8],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [9, 0,10]]])
```

The output that I would like  would be the location of the subarray and the x and y coordinates representing the centers:

```
#output:
array([[ 0., 0., 0.],
[ 0., 1.5, 2.],
[ 0., 2., 0.],
[ 1., 1.,  2.],
[ 2., 0.5,  0.],
[ 2., 1.66666667, 1.66666667],
[ 3., 0., 0.],
[ 3., 0., 2.],
[ 3., 2., 0.],
[ 3., 2., 2.]])
```

I am open to other outputs, but something like this would be awesome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you know the number of regions in advance, the standard technique to handle this is [k-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering); the are Python libraries with k-means support, eg scikit. A quick Google shows there's a module that does k-means with Pandas: [k-means-plus-plus](https://pyhttps://pypi.python.org/pypi/k-means-plus-plus/0.1.0pi.python.org/pypi/k-means-plus-plus/0.1.0), but it's Python 2 only.

Comment: It is a 4D-array. what is a region ?  what is index ?

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks! I will have a look at that tool

Comment: @B.M. it is 3D, the size I gave in the question was wrong, I will edit that. A region is a cluster of cells with the same value and and index is the location of the 2d sub-array in the 3d array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using functionality from the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author), one can construct a fully vectorized solution (that is, no for-loops):

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
idx = np.indices(largearray.shape).reshape(largearray.ndim, largearray.size)
label, mean = npi.group_by(largearray, axis=None).mean(idx, axis=1)
```

For large input, this should be a lot more efficient.

Note that if the labels are not unique within each subarray (they appear to be in your example, but this is not explicitly stated), but you still want to take the mean per subarray only, you could simply write this:

```
(label, subarr), mean = npi.group_by((largearray.flatten(), idx[0])).mean(idx[1:], axis=1)
```

That is, a grouping by unique tuples of subarray-index and label.

Comment: Wow, this is superfast. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Isn't the for loop [right here](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP/blob/master/numpy_indexed/grouping.py#L461)?

Comment: There is a for-loop there, but that's not the codepath followed in this case. That codepath is only used if a custom reduction function is given; all standard reductions are handled via ufunc.reduceat; which of course also does a for loop, but in C rather than python.

Comment: This is faster than my answers

Comment: Hi @EelcoHoogendoorn, [any relation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) to [EelcoHoogendoorn](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn)?

Comment: @askewchan: sorry, forgot to add a disclaimer

Answer (score 3):

You might also want to check out the [`numpy-groupies`](https://github.com/ml31415/numpy-groupies) package which deals with problems realted to this. [disclaimer: I am a co-author]. It should be faster than `numpy-indexed` (a package mentioned in another answer) as it uses `bincount` rather than `argsort` and `reduceat`.

However, your task here is simple enough that you could use `bincount` directly:

```
s0, s1, s2 = a.shape

group_counts = np.bincount(a.ravel())

idx = np.broadcast_to(np.arange(s0).reshape([s0, 1, 1]), [s0,s1,s2])
group_sum_0 = np.bincount(a.ravel(), idx.ravel()) 

idx = np.broadcast_to(np.arange(s1).reshape([1, s1, 1]), [s0,s1,s2])
group_sum_1 = np.bincount(a.ravel(), idx.ravel()) 

idx = np.broadcast_to(np.arange(s2).reshape([1, 1, s2]), [s0,s1,s2])
group_sum_2 = np.bincount(a.ravel(), idx.ravel()) 

group_mean = np.vstack((group_sum_0, group_sum_1, group_sum_2)) / group_counts

group_mean.T[1:] # this is the output you show in the question
```

Or if you want to "cheat", you could just use one of the functions in [ndimage.measurements](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass.html#scipy.ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass) from scipy.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of using `scipy.ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass`. That's the best answer, I'd say

Comment: yeah, the ndimage implementation looks pretty efficient. ufunc.reduceat has actually seemed very performant in my benchmarks; unlike ufunc.at, which somehow is awefully slow indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this?

```
n_clusters = 10
for i in range(1, n_clusters + 1):
    matches = np.transpose((largearray == i).nonzero())
    print "The center of cluster {} is at {}".format(i, np.mean(matches, axis=0))
```

```
The center of cluster 1 is at [ 0.  0.  0.]
The center of cluster 2 is at [ 0.   1.5  2. ]
The center of cluster 3 is at [ 0.  2.  0.]
The center of cluster 4 is at [ 1.  1.  2.]
The center of cluster 5 is at [ 2.   0.5  0. ]
The center of cluster 6 is at [ 2.          1.66666667  1.66666667]
The center of cluster 7 is at [ 3.  0.  0.]
The center of cluster 8 is at [ 3.  0.  2.]
The center of cluster 9 is at [ 3.  2.  0.]
The center of cluster 10 is at [ 3.  2.  2.]
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I need. Would this also be possible without a for loop?

Comment: @WilmarvanOmmeren: Then how come your expected output looks nothing like mine?

Comment: I had no idea how to solve this question. Sorry for that, but this is actually what I wanted. I updated the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fully vectorized version, using numpy only:

```
# the list of all the cluster ids
clusters = np.arange(1, n_clusters+1)

# convert to a boolean array, where mask[i] = largearray != clusters[i]
mask = np.rollaxis(clusters != largearray[...,np.newaxis], axis=-1)

# the coordinate of each item in the array
idx = np.indices(largearray.shape)

# broadcast (cluster_num, 1, ...) with (1, coord, ...)
mask, idx = np.broadcast_arrays(mask[:,np.newaxis], idx[np.newaxis,:])

# an array of the indices, with all the ones we don't care about masked out
idx_mask = np.ma.masked_array(idx, mask)

# flatten out the unneeded dimensions and average over them
means = idx_mask.reshape(idx_mask.shape[:2] + (-1,)).mean(axis=-1)
```

Giving:

```
masked_array(data =
 [[0.0 0.0 0.0]
 [0.0 1.5 2.0]
 [0.0 2.0 0.0]
 [1.0 1.0 2.0]
 [2.0 0.5 0.0]
 [2.0 1.6666666666666667 1.6666666666666667]
 [3.0 0.0 0.0]
 [3.0 0.0 2.0]
 [3.0 2.0 0.0]
 [3.0 2.0 2.0]],
             mask =
 [[False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

Note that this will also indicate which clusters are absent, by setting the mask

Comment: Note that this solution has quadratic timecomplexity in the number of clusters.

Comment: @Eelco: Why? Looks linear to me. Isn't this O(n_clusters * largearray.size)?

Comment: yes; but the number of clusters appears to be proportional to the array size

Comment: What's the complexity of your solution then?

Comment: NlogN worst case, but since the thing being grouped here is already pretty much in sorted order, id expect it to be pretty much linear as well

Answer (score 0):

On such tricky problems, the difficulty is to ensure the minimal number of operations. Masking or grouping technics often multiply useless manipulations.

The straightforward python way do that is roughly:

```
def center(largearray):
    n=largearray.max()+1
    (x,y,z)=largearray.shape
    sm=np.zeros((n,3),np.float64)
    cnt=np.zeros(n,np.float64)
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y):
            for k in range(z):
                l=largearray[i,j,k]
                sm[l,0] += i; sm[l,1] += j; sm[l,2] += k
                cnt[l]+=1
    for l in range(n):
        if cnt[l]>0:
            for m in range(3): sm[l,m] /= cnt[l]  
        else:
            for m in range(3): sm[l,m] = -1
    return sm [1:]
```

Here the (not so bad) performance  on the given array:

```
In [16]: %timeit center(largearray)
1000 loops, best of 3: 248 µs per loop
```

Fortunately, such code can be drastically accelerated with [numba](http://numba.pydata.org) :

```
In [17]: center2=numba.jit(center)

In [18]: %timeit center2(largearray)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.29 µs per loop
```

Comment: A subjective matter for sure, but in my opinion, on such tricky problems, the difficulty is clarity of intent and maintainability.

Comment: To clarify; not that performance is never important; but if a fully vectorized solution of optimal time complexity does not suffice, you probably should not be using numpy in the first place.